# Schedule cron jon error

Tags: linux, unix, cron

Written one simple script which will write the date-timestamp on logfile and every time you run the script, it will append in that logfile.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(date) >> log.txt
```

When I am trying to schedule the cronjob for every 1 minute. Its not getting executed, i mean no values are getting appended on log.txt

command executed are :

crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * * script-file-path
```

I am not logged in as root user. So I did this also

```
*/1 * * * * username script-file-path
```

Is there are permission issue ? Can only root user schedule a cronjob ?

Comment: Hard to say, but I definitely would specify an absolute path to the log file and double-check the permissions on both the directory and the log file if it already exists.

Comment: I believe the job of the cron is to run the script only, it has nothing to bother about the logfile path inside the script. When I am executing the script, values are getting appended in the log file..... The problem here is cron is not able to start my script :(

Answer (score 1):

The commands look good except the last one; The sixth field and the rest of the line is the command to be executed. Don't put a user name there, it will not work. To install a crontab for another user, you need to be root and use `crontab -e user`.

If there is a problem with `cron`, it will send you an email. Run `mail` on the computer to see them unless you have installed a mail redirection for that user.